# Excel. Share table header and column properties through document's sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am composing Excel document with my task-tables. It contains tasks, divided over several scopes. Tasks from every scope should be displayed in separate sheet. In every sheet, associated with a scope, would be a task-table with the same columns and format as other's scopes tables.

So I want to have a tamplate of such table, from which would be generated table headers and fetched column properties. I want to have only one place where i can change table's header style or column properties, and they would be applied to all task tables.

So the question is:

1. Is there functionality in excel to share entire rows through sheets?
2. Is there a way to copy cells or columns format (and other properties) using cells formulas?
3. In which way i can make a sheet, that aggregates rows from all sheets in one table?

It would be greate to have scripts or documents examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A direct way to do literally that is to enter the table headers in Named Ranges, one per header.

The the template used `="Named Range"`, as appropriate, for each header needed. If you ever need to change them, do it in the Named Range editing function. This will be reflected to each and every corner of the spreadsheet, the moment a calculation takes place. For example, if `F9` is pressed.

A slight alternative would be to have one more sheet off wherever, hidden if you like. On THAT sheet you set up all the headers as they need to look and instead of entering the header names in the Named Range editing function, you reference each of the Table Headers on the special sheet. You do your editing on the special sheet. The advantage is that you edit them as they are in place allowing you to see truly what things will look like in their natural environment.

You still use the other sheet as the template to copy into place each time you need a new sheet, and it still has the `"=Named Range"` approach for each header so that you still make the changes in one place, and one place only, and then see them reflected throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Since in several parts and with numerous answers hopefully a wiki answer is appropriate.

**1.  Share rows through sheets**

Group all the relevant sheets together (eg hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the tabs one by one for a specific selection, or click on the first tab, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the last tab for all tabs). Then anything you do on one sheet is repeated throughout.

**2a.  Copy cells using cell formulae**

To copy A1 within the same sheet use `=A1`.
To copy A1 from Sheet1 into a different sheet select A1 and Paste Special, Paste Link, or use `=Sheet1!A1`.

**2b.  Copy cell’s format (and other properties) using cells formulae**

Maybe use Format Painter (Home > Clipboard - ).

**3.  Aggregate rows from all sheets**

Maybe use Consolidate (Data > Data Tools - ).

Comment: You described steps of manual copying of table headers. But i want to do it automatically. I want to have one sheet for table template, and copy it's headers rows to other sheets. If i change template, other tables would be changed.